# SQL Server : no cache for single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching

I'm trying to optimize a query but after the first time I run the query the time goes down to 0.2sec.

Is there a way to run that query while specifying I don't want to use cache?

I found a few options below but they either involve a stored procedure or clearing the whole cache. While I am using a testing database, that database is shared with quite a few people trying to do their jobs and I don't want to interfere with that.

```
Dbcc freeproccache
dbcc dropcleanbuffers
dbcc freesystemcache
dbcc freesessioncache
WITH RECOMPILE - for stored procedures
```

Comment: Can't you set up your own, separate testing database and just use the `DBCC FreeProcCache` after each run?

Comment: our db is VERY big and not feasible to create a new one just so i can test 1 query :(

Comment: You can't clear just a part of the data cache, AFAIK. You can remove a single cached plan from plan cache, but it's not what you're after here. Try the SET STATISTICS IO ON and keep watch on logical reads instead of elapsed time, it's a pretty good measure also.

Comment: ERROR: The executeUpdate method must not return a result set.
    
    Query
    = SET STATISTICS IO ON
    select * from mmc.dbo.pmd
    data2 with(nolock)
    inner join mmc.dbo.pmd2
    def with(nolock)
    on data2.pmd2id = def.pmdid
    SET
    STATISTICS IO OFF